# Android In app purchases Server Error DF-AA-20

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api

Hope you all are fine. I am trying to add in app purchases in my app.. Using google demo `Trivial drive`. I configure each and every thing in my play store account.. I don't know why I still am getting error retrieving information for the server. [DF-AA-20] Please anybody know the solution.. Much appreciated.. :)

[image]

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: https://github.com/alihitawala/TrivialDrivev2

Comment: i use this demo app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says in the [Testing in-app billing tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html) you need to upload a version of your App to the Play store and publish it (even if only to an Alpha testing track) before you can try In-app billing.

Comment: We have uploaded it in alpha still getting the error. What can be done?

Comment: @VivekSancheti Hi. I have the same issue. Did you resolve it and if so, how?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54491289/android-in-app-billing-subscription-purchase-gives-error-df-aa-20?noredirect=1#comment95788565_54491289